# How to create a tab view (category) similar to instagram's explore tab

Tags: android, android-xml, android-tablayout

What i'm looking for is **creating tab layout that can expand and collapse it's height when scrolling the content below**. If anyone has any idea about how we can achieve it than it will be really helpful.

When Expanded It looks like this

[image]

When Collapsed It looks like this

[image]

Comment: please share xml file

Comment: Please when you ask share some code or something and if you faced with problems then we can help you but here you have the complete code for Instagram Clone.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpJRgr6HzAw&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE9XqkckEJJA0I1wVKbUAOdv

Comment: @VishalThakkar Haven't created it as i'm not sure how to achieve this. was trying to do it with the collapsing toolbar layout but it is not helping.

Comment: @Spritzig I have gone through that video course but haven't found what i'm looking for. I just want to create a tab view similar to instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no answer was posted and I found the solution to these I'm posting the solution as an answer to this question.

So, here is what I have done.

I have taken two recyclerViews

1. For Showing Category (horizontal Scrolling) (id = rvCategoryList)
2. For Showing Items of the category (Vertical Scrolling) (id = rvItemList)

Now have taken two variable for keeping the track of the last scroll and created a method to set the height of the rvCategoryList

```
var lastY: Int = 0
var counter = 0
private fun setCategoryViewHeight(dy: Int) {
    val params = rvCategoryList.layoutParams
    if ((dy > 0 && lastY >= 0) || (dy < 0 && lastY <= 0)) {
        counter = 0
        params.height = params.height - dy
        if (dy > 0) {
            if (params.height < rvHeight / 1.7) {
                params.height = (rvHeight / 1.7).toInt()
            }
        } else {
            if (params.height > rvHeight) {
                params.height = rvHeight
            }
        }
        rvCategoryList.layoutParams = params
        lastY = dy
    } else {
        counter++
        if (counter > 2) {
            counter = 0
            lastY = 0
        }
    }
}
```

And Have applied OnScrollListener on the rvItemList as below.

```
rvItemList.clearOnScrollListeners()
rvItemList.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        lastY = 0 //As the scroll state has been changed reinitializing the lastY variable.
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        setCategoryViewHeight(dy) //Setting height everytime.
    }
})
```

I hope this will help someone who wants to create a similar view.